# URL Rewriting, create fakesubfolders with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect that kind of URL :

`http://mydomain.com/Site/1-Test.htm`

To :

`http://mydomain.com/index.php?View=Site&Par=1`

With apache2 And mod_rewrite, but I can't find a way to make it works.

Here is the code I use in my .htaccess file :

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)-(.+)\.htm$ index.php?View=$1&Par=$2 [QSA,L]
```

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: The ending of your URL is `.html`, but your expression accepts only `.htm`

Comment: This is just a typo in the copy past.